# How to fuse color images using Inverse Discrete Wavelet Transform?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using the `idwt2()` function available in Matlab to on a fused image.

```matlab
c=idwt2(a3,b3,c3,d3,'db2');
```

However the image cannot be displayed using,

```matlab
figure,imshow(c)
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

But appears to work just fine when the following is used:

```matlab
figure,imshow(c,[])
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Can anyone please tell me why it can display a grayscale picture and not a RGB one?

Comment: `[]` does not convert to grayscale, just automatically sets the color range. The problem does not seem to have much to do with RGB/gray, but we'd need a [mcve] to help more. It just seems the image was gray to start with.

Comment: Sure! The entire code with the images used are provided here. [link] (https://github.com/ritwikraha/Image-Fusion-Analysis). I have used RGB images but feel free to check.